# Cannot add icon to project resources mono develop

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I made a new GTK# project added a toolbar and tried to add button to it. I tried to add a custom icon. I clicked on New Button, the on the newly created button -> select icon -> more -> project icons, and added my icon to the project. The icon appears normal in the editor, as shown on the screen shot below:
[image]

But when I try to run it, the following error occurs:

```
Error MSB5016: The name "DeployService.UseProjectRelativePath" contains an invalid character ".". (MSB5016)
```

Googling didn't help :( Anyone else had the similar problem? Thanks!

Edit1: Cleaning or rebuilding project also doesn't work, even after the icon is removed, but the application compiled successfully before the icon was added.

Comment: funnily enough, closing and reopening MonoDev. solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the resource in you project (the icon), right-click it, select "build action" and set it to "embbeded resource".

Then you need to access it. If you are using the designer, then don't need anything else, but if you want to access it programmatically in Windows Forms (and your project is called "my-project" and your icon is under folder "Res")

```
this.bmpAppIcon = new Bitmap(
                    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly( ).
                        GetManifestResourceStream( 
                            "my-project.Res.appIcon.png" ) );
```

If you are working with Gtk# (you'll have to specify the size here):

```
this.Icon = new Gdk.Pixbuf(
                    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(),
                    "my-project.Res.appIcon.png", 32, 32 );
```